# Has anyone successfully implemented react-native headless js?

Tags: react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/headless-js-android.html#headless-js

I can't seem to find the right way to do it

I am running React-native 0.40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented the `HeadlessJsTaskService` to execute some react native code.

For me the `ReactExecutorService` just silently failed, because i didn't provide any Extras when calling `startService(new Intent(this, MyTaskService.class));`. The following code fixes that:

```
@Override
@Nullable
protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null;
    return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "FeatureExecutor",
            data,
            5000);
}
```

I also had an existing Application class, that didn't implement `ReactApplication`. I had to add some code to make the `HeadlessJsTaskService` work:

```
private final ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                // Insert your packages, e.g.
                new MainReactPackage()
        );
    }
};

@Override
public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return reactNativeHost;
}
```

You also have to add your custom service to the manifest. For example:

```
<service android:name=".MyTaskService"/>
```

Please provide some additional information about your issues in case the solutions above do not help.

Comment: I'm a bit confusing, where do you put you ReactExecutorService.java file ? in this rout : `node_mudoles/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/jstasks/` and edit manifest file in this `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` directory ?

Comment: if you can please create step by step guide